# How to config cocoapod podspec and podfile for this project structure?

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

Hi my project folder is structured like this:

```
+ Podfile
+ Apps/
  |
  +  Apps.xcodeproj
  | 
  +  Target1/
  | 
  +  Target2/

+ AppLib/
  |
  + AppLib.podspec
  |
  + AppLib.xcodeproj
  |
  + TargetLib1/
  | 
  + TargetLib2/
```

My dependencies structure like this

`Apps` -- depend --> `AppLib`

`AppLib` -- depend --> `RestKit` and `MagicalRecord`

Here is how i config my **podfile**

```
workspace 'MyApp'
xcodeproj 'Apps/Apps'
xcodeproj 'AppLib/AppLib'


def import_pods
  pod 'AppLib', :path => './AppLib'
end

target 'Target1' do
  platform :ios, '7.0'
  import_pods
  xcodeproj 'Apps/Apps'
end

target 'Target1' do
  platform :ios, '7.0'
  import_pods
  xcodeproj 'Apps/Apps'
end
```

And here is the `AppLib.podspec`:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  s.name         = "AppLib"
  s.version      = "0.0.1"
  s.summary      = "Common library."
  s.platform     = :ios, "7.0"
  s.source_files  = "Lib/Public/**/*.{h,m}"
  s.ios.deployment_target = '7.0'
  s.resources = "Lib/Nibs/**/*.xib"
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.dependency 'RestKit', '~> 0.23'
  s.dependency 'MagicalRecord'
end
```

At root folder (folder contains Podfile) `pod install` run without problem
But when i import RestKit `#import "RestKit.h"` or `#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>` in my AppLibs project, xcode say that the file is not found.

Are my podfile and podspec correct?
Why xcode claim that RestKit.h is not found?

If I want to build AppLibs separately, how to pull all the dependencies?
(`pod install` does not work with .podspec file) do i need to create another podfile in `AppLib` folder?

Comment: You could try adding "headers" section in your podspec and specify RestKit and MagicalRecord headers there. Though I think CocoaPods should handle this by itself

Answer (score 0):

Well, my goals were

1. Let the lib be built and shipped separately
2. Manage dependencies of both the app and lib with CocoaPods
3. Avoid duplication as much as possible
4. Use lib and app from one workspace to debug easily

What I've ended with is

1. Separate git repos for the lib and the app
2. Each repo has its own podfile
3. Lib's repo is a git submodule of app's one
4. Lib's project is included into app's workspace
5. App links the lib in an old-fashioned way with
   'LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATH', 'USER_HEADERS_SEARCH_PATH'. To not let the
   CocoaPods mangle my lib folder structure (if you attach lib as dev pod, it does that).
6. Lib has a podspec listing dependencies, lib's podfile just grabs
   deps from there with 'podspec' command
7. App's podfile does the same (podspec 'lib/Lib.podspec'), thus
   referring to all the dependencies of the lib.

That's it, hope it helps.